# How do I unit test openWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, ios5, objective-c-blocks

I have a unit test module derived from `SenTestCase`. I would like to have a unit test method that would load a `UIDocument` derived document I saved on the application sandbox previously. Note this test is about loading the document locally (iCloud is not configured). I know `openWithCompletionHandler` runs asynchronously so I understand this would never work as soon as the test function runs off the stack. Below code is given to indicate my intention (of course it doesn't work):

```
-(void)testLoadingDocument{
    ...
    MyDocument *document = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:destUrl];
    STAssertNotNil(document, @"Document is nil");

    NSLog(@"LOAD: %@", document.fileURL);
    [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"openWithCompletionHandler success = %@", success);
        if (success) {
            // document.packet will be filled by loadFromContents
            STAssertNotNil(document.packet, @"document.packet is nil.");
        }
    }];
}
```

My question is really is there any way to test `openWithCompletionHandler` from within unit testing framework? I don't mind if I have to run the entire document loading operation synchronously within a block of code. Since this is a test code I thought this would be acceptable unlike code that has to run asynchronously on the device.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I now think there is a better way to achieve this. I realised what I really want is to test contentsForType and loadFromContents. So in my test suite I'll create a mock class derived from MyDocument that will implement saveToUrl and openWithCompletionHandler that will simply synchronously redirect contentsForType and loadFromContents calls to MyDocument. There is no point of dealing with async file i/o stuff if your purpose is to test data processing in those methods. If that fixes my problem then I'll come and update this question.

Comment: I created a memory mapped UIDocument derived class and an NSMutableData derived class in which I wrapped my data class implementing NSCoding protocol. I crafted a few delegations. But it didn't work. I have to move on with my project, so I am giving up on unit testing UIDocument. If you can point out better strategies please do so. I am still interested to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem took me a while to figure out. I love unit testing, but when using `SenTestCase` your tests do not run in the same environment your regular code would. Most importantly, you lack a main loop that has a run loop in it, making anything with async call backs prone to doing nothing.

So what's the solution? Provide a run loop ourselves and have it run until the block gets called. We use a `__block` variable that we set in the completion block to see when we can stop running the run loop.

```
-(void)testOfAsyncCallingMethod{

    __block bool wasCalled = NO;

    [testingObject methodThatRunsACompletionBlock:^{
        wasCalled = YES;
    }];

    NSDate *loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    while (wasCalled == NO && [loopUntil timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:loopUntil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply and thanks very much @redlightbulb